# Serial port library across different compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, library, portability, serial-port

I'm writing a C++ library with MinGW (4.8.0, DW2, POSIX) compiler. But this library must be used by another compiler. I've read this [post](http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html), so I've re-written the C++ library interface in this way:

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#include <cstring>          // size_t
#include <memory>           // unique_ptr

#if defined( _MSC_VER ) || defined( __MINGW32__ ) || defined( __MINGW64__ )
#   define SERIALPORT_IMPORT __declspec( dllimport )
#   define SERIALPORT_EXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
#   define SERIALPORT_CALL __stdcall
#elif defined( __GNUG__ ) && !defined( WIN32 )
#   define SERIALPORT_IMPORT
#   define SERIALPORT_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#else
#   define SERIALPORT_IMPORT
#   define SERIALPORT_EXPORT
#endif

#if defined( SERIALPORT_EXPORTS )
#   define SERIALPORT_API SERIALPORT_EXPORT
#else
#   define SERIALPORT_API SERIALPORT_IMPORT
#endif

namespace serialport {

/**
 * @brief Milliseconds_t rappresent a duration of time expressed in milliseconds
 */
typedef unsigned long Milliseconds_t;

/**
 * Possible read return value.
 */
enum ReadStatus
{
    SERIAL_OK,
    SERIAL_TIMEOUT,
    SERIAL_ERROR
};

/**
 * Interface to access to a serial port
 */
class ISerialPort {
public:    
    /**
     * @brief operator delete overload the delete operator so we can destroy
     *        class inside shared library bounds.
     */
    void operator delete( void* p )
    {
        if ( p )
        {
            ISerialPort* s = static_cast< ISerialPort* >( p );
            s->destroy();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get serial port path
     */
    virtual const char* SERIALPORT_CALL getDeviceName() const = 0;

    /**
     * Get serial port baudrate
     */
    virtual int SERIALPORT_CALL baudrate() const = 0;


    /**
     * Flush serial port rx and tx buffers.
     */
    virtual void SERIALPORT_CALL flush() = 0;

    /**
     * @brief setTimeout set the serial port timeout
     * @param timeout_ms timeout in milliseconds
     */
    virtual void SERIALPORT_CALL setTimeout( Milliseconds_t timeout_ms ) = 0;


    /**
     * @brief getTimeoutGet serial port timeouts.
     * @return serial port timeouts in milliseconds
     */
    virtual Milliseconds_t SERIALPORT_CALL getTimeout() const = 0;


    /**
     * Read data from serial port in the specified timeout.
     * @param[out] buffer pointer to the destination buffer.
     * @param[in] size size in bytes of data that must be read.
     * @throw SerialTimeout if a timeout occured
     */
    virtual ReadStatus SERIALPORT_CALL read( void* buffer, size_t size ) const = 0;


    /**
     * Read data from serial port the aviable data.
     * @param[out] buffer storage where to put incoming data.
     * @param[in] size size in bytes of data that must be read.
     * @return SerialBuffer buffer containing the data.
     */
    virtual size_t SERIALPORT_CALL readSome( void* buffer, size_t size ) const = 0;


    /**
     * Read data from serial port in a infinite timeout.
     * @param[out] buffer pointer to the destination buffer.
     * @param[in] size size in bytes of data that must be read.
     */
    virtual void SERIALPORT_CALL read_n( void* buffer, size_t size ) const = 0;


    /**
     * Send data to the serial port.
     * @param[out] buffer pointer to the destination buffer.
     * @param[in] size size in bytes of data that must be read.
     */
    virtual void SERIALPORT_CALL send( const void* orig, size_t size ) const = 0;

protected:
    /**
     * @brief ~ISerialPort The destructor is protected to avoid that library is
     *        deleted outside dll bounds.
     */
    virtual ~ISerialPort() {}


    /**
     * @brief destroy need to free resource: we cannot use dctor so operator delete
     *        will call destroy() to release the resource
     */
    virtual void SERIALPORT_CALL destroy() = 0;
};


/**
 * @brief The SerialDeleter class is used by SerialPtr to safely delete the class
 */
class SerialDeleter
{
public:
    void operator() ( ISerialPort* s )
    {
       s->destroy();
    }
};

} // serialport namespace

typedef std::unique_ptr < serialport::ISerialPort, serialport::SerialDeleter > SerialPtr;

/**
 * Factory function for creating a serial port class
 * @param path path of the serial port.
 * @param baudrate baudrate of the serial port.
 */
extern "C" SERIALPORT_API serialport::ISerialPort* CreateSerialPort( const char* deviceName, int baudrate );

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

Assuming the compiler is C++11-compliant (I've tested with Visual C++ 2013), is this a good interface for cross-compiler integration?

Comment: This is not a good solution: The code above if compiled with MinGW won't work correctly on msvc compiler.

Answer (score 9):

- You should just include [`<cstddef>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef) in order to use `std::size_t`.  Including `<cstring>` seems unnecessary if you're not actually going to utilize anything else.
- Since this is C++11, you can now use [strongly-typed `enum`s](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19083/C-2011-Stronglytyped-Enums.htm) over plain ones.  One difference is that plain `enum`s are implicitly cast to `int`, whereas strongly-typed ones must be explicitly cast in order to not be implicitly cast as well.
- Both of these classes have no `private` fields, so they can just become `struct`s, which are `public` by default.

Answer (score 8):

I have a number of questions that you might find useful to answer for yourself with the idea of improving your code.

### Are `read` and `send` really `const`?

It would be a most unusual implementation of a serial port class that didn't actually modify internal state when doing a `read` or `send` operation.  These should probably not be declared `const`, including variations such as `readSome`.

### Does `operator delete` need a header?

I suspect that you will want to `#include <new>` because that is where your `operator delete` is defined.

### What about constructors?

This interface provides no constructors, which is probably not realistic.  Specifically, if you're using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), the class would probably need to acquire a particular serial port and initialize it for use.  It may also be a useful place to document default baudrate and timeout if you have such for your class. Your factory function `CreateSerialPort` would be most useful if it returned an initialized instance and that initialization is probably more reasonably the domain of the class itself rather than the factory class.

### Do `readSome` and `read_n` never `throw` exceptions?

You have nicely documented the interface, including noting that `read` can `throw` a `SerialTimeout` exception.  It seems likely that the other functions could also `throw` that exception unless they're blocking functions, in which case it would be nice to explicitly say.  For example, `read_n` says that it uses `infinite timeout` which implies blocking without specifically saying so.

### Have you run a spell check on comments?

If you run a spell check on your comments, you'll find a number of things such as "aviable" instead of "available" and "rappresent" instead of "represent".  Since your code is nicely commented, it's worth the extra step to eliminate spelling errors.

### What about `move` constructors?

Although your use of the class through `SerialPtr` seems intended to eliminate the possibility of inadvertent copies, the class can still be moved but the class provides no such call.  This means that the compiler-provided `move` constructor will be used.  This may be fine, but it's worth documenting in the interface if that is really your intent.

### Does the factory actually create a `SerialPtr`?

If your factory function actually creates a `unique_ptr` rather than a mere instance pointer, it's probably worth saying so explicitly in the comments or in the declaration.  I understand that there may be some problems in doing so due to the fact that you're passing things through a "C" interface because of the limitations of the Windows interface.